# How to compare nested multilevel path models

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, model-comparison

I have two multilevel path models, one is nested in the other and I want to compare the models to see whether I should prefer the full or nested model.

The models have cross-level interactions and I am currently using Mplus with a bayesian estimator. However, Mplus doesn't have (as far as I have been able to find) a way to compare models outside of things the DIC (for example DIFTEST doesn't work for Bayesian ML-SEM).

Similarly, R's Mplusautomation package has a model comparison function, but it doesn't seem to produce something like a chi-square Log Likelihood ratio for Bayesian estimators. Although alternative packages like Lavaan handle ML-SEM and can be compared relatively easily with a Likelihood Ratio Test, it doesn't currently support cross-level interactions (as far as I know).

I am looking for suggestions on how to compare two nested multilevel path models with cross level interactions. I am aware you can use the DICs, but I am a bit lost as to what constitutes a meaningful difference between two DICs. So any advice in this direction would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variability of casewise likelihoods forms a basis for calculating a *SE* or CI around (differences in) information criteria, but I think that is also not available in M*plus*. `blavaan` obtains them from the `loo` package, but `blavaan` does not yet handle MLSEM, although you could simply code up the model manually in Stan (`rstan` package) to utilize the `loo` package.

If the models are *parametrically* nested (i.e., the more restricted model is equivalent to the less restricted model by fixing one or more of its parameters), then you can conduct a Bayesian version of the Wald test from M*plus* version 8.4: http://www.statmodel.com/download/BayesFit.pdf

Note that Wald (and score) tests are asymptotically equivalent to a LRT ([Buse, 1982](https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.1982.10482817)), so hopefully this provides the information you are looking for.

Comment: The models are parametrically nested so the Wald test should do the trick. Thank you!